# wordpress Astra Theme: Pagination Issue on Blog Pages

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using the Astra theme on my WordPress site, but I am facing an issue with pagination on my blog pages. Even after using pagination plugins, the pagination is not showing up. Does anyone know where I should paste the "pagination code" on the blog page?

I have tried various plugins and watched numerous YouTube videos, but unfortunately, I haven't found any helpful solutions yet.